# Angular forms: loosing input value after "@" symbol

Tags: angular

Here's my form:

```
<form class="inbox col-sm-10" action="" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="label"></span>
    <button class="btn btn-control btn-send" type="submit" [ngClass]="{hidden: !!letter._id}">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-control btn-back" (click)="clickBack()" >Go back</button>
  </div>

  <div class="to">
    <span class="label">to:</span>
    <span class="input">
      <input class="mail-to" type="text" typeahead formControlName="to">
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="subject">
    <span class="label">subject:</span>
    <span class="input">
      <input class="mail-subject" type="text" formControlName="subject">
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="body">
    <span class="label">body:</span>
    <span class="input">
      <textarea class="mail-body" formControlName="body" cols="30" rows="10">{{letter.body}}</textarea>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here are methods of filling form in and saving form data (whole class is too long):

```
  createForm(letter?: ILetter) {
    if (letter) {
      // existing letter
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        'to': this.letter.to,
        'subject': this.letter.subject,
        'body': this.letter.body
      });
    } else {
      // new letter
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        'to': undefined,
        'subject': undefined,
        'body': undefined
      });
    }
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    this.letter.to = this.form.value.to;
    this.letter.body = this.form.value.body;
    this.letter.subject = this.form.value.subject;

    this.lettersService
        .saveLetter(this.letter)
        .subscribe((dat) => {
          this.router.navigate(['/mail/sent']);
        },
        err => console.log('ERROR: ' + err)
        );
  }
```

The problem is that the "to" fields value cut after "@" simbol. I.e. if the value is "john@mail.com" then `this.form.value.to` will contain "john" and if remove "@" simbol from the input the value will be "johnmail.com"...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Appears to include the @mail.com portion http://plnkr.co/edit/dp2d7VIwIRKivpjbqAKS?p=preview

Comment: This <input> tag is filled by the directive "typeahead" directly (`evt.target.value = ...`), and I have found that the value inserted into a form's field by the directive (or any other code) is not passed into the FormGroup. So I fixed this by passing formGroup into the directive.
Thanks a lot for your code on Plunker - it really made me think in a right way